# Hyperlinking specific text after hitting the space bar in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an C# ASP.NET MVC 4 application that requires this in a textbox. Basically, I'm looking to hyperlink project numbers in this format: ABC-123 (3 upper case letters, followed by a dash, followed by any number of numbers), this can be handled by a regex obviously, however, I just don't know where this part will fit in with the rest of what I need to do.

So what I'm mainly after typing ABC-123, I want that project number to hyperlink to itself (The URL will have this number at the end) after I've typed it and hit the space bar.

I've looked around online for a few hours researching rich text boxes and Jquery, but I haven't found anything solid that I think I could use. If anybody could gladly point me in the direction I need to be going in, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Are you looking for something like a facebook-style multi-select like http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ or http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-04-10/a-facebook-style-multiselect.aspx?

Comment: A similar manner to that yes, but I just want it to be a hyperlink I can click on. Also, I don't believe kendo ui is something that's free is it? I'm not looking to buy, just use whatever is free.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me a matter of [event handling.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (*if you want to "DIY"*)

[Here is the most relevant](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88ae8842-5301-4b15-830e-1d6282303508/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-inputs) material (capturing keystrokes):

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
{
   switch(keyData)
      {
         case Keys.Down:
            Console.WriteLine("Down Arrow Captured");
            break;

         case Keys.Up:
            Console.WriteLine("Up Arrow Captured");
            break;

         case Keys.Tab:
            Console.WriteLine("Tab Key Captured");
            break;

         case Keys.Control | Keys.M:
            Console.WriteLine("<CTRL> + m Captured");
            break;

         case Keys.Alt | Keys.Z:
            Console.WriteLine("<ALT> + z Captured");
            break;
      }
}
```

[This MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88ae8842-5301-4b15-830e-1d6282303508/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-inputs) instructs on keyboard listening.

If I'm understanding correctly, you're just listening for a spacebar input, and then modifying a string and potentially change into an object like a [hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: That sounds right about what I'm looking for, I'll investigate the links you posted there.

Comment: I just supplemented my answer with some less-opinionated info. Hope it helps.

Comment: An interesting chunk of code you have posted, was this taken from the link you posted earlier? If not, I'm wondering how this chunk of code gets activated

Comment: I just did some deeper research and the actual source of that code is this support post: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320584. It has another tutorial about trapping keystrokes.